# How do I fix "error: constructor (class) in class (class) cannot be applied to given types;"

Tags: java, class, object

So I'm writing this a piece of code to create a mini-database type program that uses abstract classes or whatnot. I've gotten to my driver code, where I'm creating 2 new objects; one with random parameters, and the other with the first object.

```
Student test1 = new Student("Jack", "jackjack@test.com", "Math", 3.9, 10);
BandMember test2 = new BandMember(test1);
```

But when I run my program, this error occurs:

```
CollegeDatabase.java:122: error: constructor BandMember in class BandMember cannot be applied to given types;
    BandMember test2 = new BandMember(test1);
                       ^
required: String,String,String,double,int
found: Student
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

I'm really confused as to why this error is occurring. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me resolve this issue. Thank you!

(keep in mind I'm a novice at java currently :I)

Here's my CollegeDatabase.java:

```
abstract class Person{
    public String emailAddress, personName;
    
    public Person(String name, String email){
        System.out.println("created person");
        name = personName;
        email = emailAddress;
    }
    
    public String returnName(){
        return personName;
    }
    
    public String returnEmail(){
        return emailAddress;
    }
    
    public void editName(String newName){
        personName = newName;
        System.out.println("successfully changed name");
    }
    
    public void editEmail(String newEmail){
        emailAddress = newEmail;
        System.out.println("successfully changed email");
    }
}

class Student extends Person{
    public String majorSubject;
    public double gradePointAverage;
    public int gradeLevel;
    
    public Student(String name, String email, String major, double gpa, int grade){
        super(name, email);
        major = majorSubject;
        gpa = gradePointAverage;
        grade = gradeLevel;
    }
    
    public void changeGPA(double newGPA){
        gradePointAverage = newGPA;
        System.out.println("changed gpa");
    }
    
    public void changeMajor(String newMajor){
        majorSubject = newMajor;
        System.out.println("changed major");
    }
    
    public void changeGrade(int newGrade){
        gradeLevel = newGrade;
        System.out.println("changed grade");
    } 
    
    
    public double getGPA(){
        return gradePointAverage;
    }
    
    public String getMajor(){
        return majorSubject;
    }
    
    public int getGrade(){
        return gradeLevel;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Name: "+personName+", Email: "+emailAddress+", Major: "+majorSubject+", GPA: "+gradePointAverage+", Grade: "+gradeLevel+"th";
    }
}

class BandMember{
    private String name, email, major, instrument;
    private double gpa;
    private int grade;
    
    public BandMember(String name, String email, String major, double gpa, int grade){
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.major = major;
        this.gpa = gpa;
        this.grade = grade;
        System.out.println("created new band member");
    }
    public void assignInstruments(){
        if(grade == 9){
            instrument = "bells";
        }
        else if(grade == 10){
            instrument = "trumpet";
        }
        else if(grade == 11){
            instrument = "baritone";
        }
        else if (grade == 12){
            instrument = "tuba";
        }
    }
    public void changeInstrument(String instrument){
        this.instrument = instrument;
        System.out.println("successfuly changed instruments");
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        return "Name: "+name+", Email: "+email+", Major: "+major+", GPA: "+gpa+", Grade: "+grade+"th, Instrument: "+instrument;
    }
}

public class CollegeDatabase{
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Student test1 = new Student("Jack", "jackjack@test.com", "Math", 3.9, 10);
        
        test1.editName("Jill");
        test1.editEmail("jilljill@test.com");
        test1.changeGPA(4.0);
        test1.changeMajor("computer science");
        test1.changeGrade(11);
        
        BandMember test2 = new BandMember(test1);
        //error is above ^
        test2.assignInstruments();

        System.out.println(test1);
        System.out.println(test2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you use `Getters` and `Setters` over `Return`, `Edit`, and `Change`.

Comment: Aside from the problem addressed by the answer, your constructors are wrong. They assign the value from the field (which will be null or zero) to the parameter, instead of assigning the parameter to the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no constructor in `Bandmember` class that accepts a student as an argument. The constructor currently looks like this: `public BandMember(String name, String email, String major, double gpa, int grade)`. I understand that you might want to create a new `Bandmember` with a `student`. Then you can create another constructor inside the `Bandmember` class. Here is a template that should work.

```
public BandMember(Student student){
    this.name = student.returnName();
    this.email = student.returnEmail();
    this.major = student.getMajor();
    this.gpa = student.getGPA();
    this.grade = student.getGrade();
    System.out.println("created new band member");
}
```

Comment: @JaydenGu consider accepting the answer if the question has been answered. Lets other people know that you the question has been answered :)